# Apache http core nio 4.3.3 reverse proxy SSL error

Tags: ssl, nio, reverse-proxy, apache-httpcomponents

I am developing a reverse proxy using http core nio 4.3.3 and need to connect to a Secure/HTTPS endpoint via the proxy. I took the reverse proxy(Asynchronous HTTP reverse proxy)[1] and added SSL support as shown below.

```
    SSLContext clientSSLContext =
                       SSLUtil.createClientSSLContext(TRUST_STORE_LOCATION,
                                                      TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);

    final IOEventDispatch connectingEventDispatch =
                                                    new DefaultHttpClientIODispatch(
                                                                                    clientHandler,
                                                                                    clientSSLContext,
                                                                                    ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
    ...
    connectingIOReactor.execute(connectingEventDispatch);
```

When I send the request, I am getting this error,

**java.io.IOException: SSL not supported**

The Stack trace is given below.

**[client<-proxy] 00000001 java.io.IOException: SSL not supported
java.io.IOException: SSL not supported
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.pool.BasicNIOConnFactory.create(BasicNIOConnFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.pool.BasicNIOConnFactory.create(BasicNIOConnFactory.java:1)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestCompleted(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:484)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.completed(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:770)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.completed(SessionRequestImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processNewChannels(AbstractIOReactor.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:288)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)**

I enabled SSL debug logs as well, but still could not figure out the issue.
 Then I debugged this and found out that the proxy received the request from the client and drops due to an exception inside the handle method of HttpAsyncRequestConsumer. The exception is java.io.IOException: SSL not supported

Also note that the SSLContext was working fine with a reverse proxy written using the netty transport.

Any help would be appreciated.

[1] https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html

Regards,
Ravindra.

Answer (score 1):

When using a connection pool on the client side to manage outgoing connections one needs to ensure that the connection factory used by the pool to create new connection objects is SSL capable. Please make sure that the connection pool is properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the advice. That solved the issue.

```
        clientSSLContext =
                           SSLUtil.createClientSSLContext(TRUST_STORE_LOCATION,
                                                          TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);
        BasicNIOConnFactory connectionFactory =
                                                new BasicNIOConnFactory(
                                                                        clientSSLContext,
                                                                        null,
                                                                        ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
        proxyConnPool = new ProxyConnPool(connectingIOReactor, connectionFactory, 5000)
```

Comment: Hey if you could share your complete code sample, that'd be awesome. I've been trying to modify the example to do SSL as well, but I can't see how your code fits in at all. There must have been other modifications, no? Anyway if you could that'd be great. Thanks.